# Why is it »aus führen« and not »ausführen«?

Tags: verb-usage, separable-verb

The transcript of DW Langsam gesprochene Nachrichten from today has the sentence

> Sie werde die Regierungsgeschäfte von zu Hause **aus führen**.

I might have thought that the space between **aus** and **führen** was a typo, except that Reverso Dictionary shows 6 additional examples of sentences with the same spacing. But I can find nothing in Duden to support it. What is going on?

https://www.dw.com/de/10072020-langsam-gesprochene-nachrichten/a-54121374

https://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/aus+f%C3%BChren

Comment: I recently came across something similar: *Ich studiere momentan die hiesige Flora und Fauna von meinem Heimlabor aus.* (From the German version of Stardew Valley.) I think it's basically the same idiom as "(someone is doing something) from out of (some location)" in English, it's just that German changes the word order somewhat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The verb used is `führen`, not `ausführen`
In your sentence, `aus` belongs to `von zu Hause aus`, describing the place: from home.

A rough translation might be

> She would lead the affairs of state from home.

Compare:

> I'm working at home: `Ich arbeite zu Hause`
> I'm working from home: `Ich arbeite von zu Hause aus`

See e.g. https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=german&query=von+zu+hause+aus for further examples.